# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I have a question about the iOS：

[image]

but

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you sure all your variables are correctly defined?

Comment: enter sarcastic comment here

Comment: @Lorenzo yes, I have to import the file.But still an error

Comment: what is your xcode version? This is the project setting problem. got to Project->Build Active Architechure Only-> [add here] armv7,armv7s,armv 64  if you are using xcode 6/xcode 5

Comment: do you have a library named "libmp3lame.a"?

Comment: @jamil65able Yes, I have it

Comment: what is your xcode version?

Comment: @jamil65able Xcode7  Valid Architechures: armv7,armv7s,armv 64

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't import `.m` file by mistake instead of `.h`, and that all headers are imported in the first place.